# Form Data Select passing 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, c#, razor-pages

I am having an issue with my Form Submit function

Everything is submitting as expected other than the 'Option' from my 'Select'.

It is getting passed through as 'Undefined'

I'm wondering if this is because the Options in the select are generated programmatically at runtime?

My code for the select is:

```
        <label for="devname">Developer Name:</label>
        <select id="devname" name="devname">
            <option  value="">Choose name..</option>
        </select><br><br>
```

The code i've got that generates the options is:

```
function populateSelect() {
    $.get('/GetDevs').done(function (devs){
        var index = 0;
        var selectme = document.getElementById('devname');
        for (index = 0; index < devs.length; ++index) {
            var dev = devs[index];
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = dev.Devid;
            opt.innerHTML = dev.dname;
            selectme.appendChild(opt);
        }
    });
}
populateSelect();
```

This successfully populates the option but as i say, when i post the form it gets passed 'undefined'

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Did you check that the option elements are rendered correctly with value? And how did get the selected option before post?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply this helped solve the issue :) I wasnt actually giving the options any valid values, once i did that the code ran smoothly. Thanks for the help